# Problem installing ROS Groovy: Mobile Install

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening partners
I'm trying yo install the mobile on a Raspberry pi running Raspbian at step 3.1 of Groovy Installation Guide.
Following the recommendation I have been given the following error :

Using initial elements from: http packages ros org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/mobile
ERROR in config: Invalid multiproject yaml format in [http //packages ros org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/mobile]: mapping values are not allowed here
in "", line 14, column 20

I have deleted dots because I can't publish links yet
I can be able to continue with the installation process.
Could you help me please?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86616/problem-installing-ros-groovy:-mobile-install/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-10-03**:
Which guide are you following?

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-04**:
I was following this guide
http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian

But I have also read that we have to use rosinstall_generator.
http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator#Installation

I´m a little lost with this beacuse I´m a completely noob

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-07**:
At Step 5.6 I´m getting this : ERROR: your rosdep installation has not been initialized yet.  Please run:

```
rosdep update
```

Altought I run the update I get always the same trying "sudo rosdep check ... "

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Thanks a lot

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-08**:
I supose that it will be related; if I ignore this part and continue I can´t build the Catkin Workspace. I get this message : catkin_make It does not exist file or directory and ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosinstall generator website has been removed in favor of using the command line tool [rosintall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator)

Whatever instructions you are following need to be updated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-04**:
Thanks

I understand that instructions that I was following are out of date so if I follow this http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator#Installation how can I get Ros Groovy functional in my Raspberry?

Whatever I have to wait for the updating ? I really need it running it on.

Thanks you so much

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-04**:
You can figure out how to substitute the command line arguments for the web query.  Also if you link to the tutorial you are following, it is much more likely to be updated.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-04**:
Sorry but as I said before I´m a beginner with this so no, I can´t figure out how to substitue the command line arguments from this
sudo wstool init -j1 src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
to make it work with the correspondient in rosinstall_generator wiki page

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-04**:
I really appreciate your interest but with answers as " You can figure out how to substitute the command line arguments for the web query" you are not helping me at all.
Sorry if my  lack of knowledge has bothered you to the point of answering so. I´ll try to get it work and wait for updates.Thanks

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
I've updated the instructions as best I can w/o testing.  Here's the diff: http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source?action=diff&rev1=105&rev2=106

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks you so much. This evening after work I´ll test and check it.
Great job and thanks to this community for everything.